# How do I revise my code to produce the desired output like the one in the picture?

Tags: tables, formatting

How do I revise my code to produce the desired output?
This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllllll}
  \hline
 & \hspace{1cm} Dyads Sample & & & \hspace{1cm} Committed Sample & &  \\
  \hline
 & Range & Mean & Sd & Range & Mean & Sd \\ 
  \hline
BAA & \{0,1\}\ & 0.418 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.306 &  \\ 
  BAF & \{0,1\}\ & 0.449 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.388 &  \\ 
  Data Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.550 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.406 &  \\ 
  Life Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.597 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.509 &  \\ 
  Engineer & \{0,1\}\ & 0.796 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.864 &  \\ 
  Previous Raised & (0,40.0] & 1.096 & 3.030 & (0,10.0] & 1.101 & 1.754 \\ 
  Max Raise & [0.2,27.7] & 2.026 & 2.658 & [0.2,20.0] & 2.947 & 2.947 \\ 
  Age & [0,18] & 3.157 & 2.738 & [0,11] & 3.188 & 2.307 \\ 
  Patent & \{0,1\}\ & 0.171 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.161 &  \\ 
  Committed & \{0,1\}\ & 0.0188 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 1 &  \\ 
  Amount (\$K) & [0,350] & 0.273 & 5.154 & [3,350] & 15.408 & 35.627 \\ 
   \hline
  \#Obs & 18618 & 18618 & 18618 & 330 & 330 & 330 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is my output:[image]

This is the desired output:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum, you need to replace the line

```
& \hspace{1cm} Dyads Sample & & & \hspace{1cm} Committed Sample & & \\
```

with

```
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dyads Sample} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Committed Sample} \\
```

I would go further, though, and employ the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline` to provide more structure *and* visual appeal to the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc ccc @{}}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dyads Sample} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Committed Sample} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
  & Range & Mean & Sd & Range & Mean & Sd \\ 
  \midrule
  BAA & \{0,1\}\ & 0.418 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.306 &  \\ 
  BAF & \{0,1\}\ & 0.449 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.388 &  \\ 
  Data Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.550 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.406 &  \\ 
  Life Science & \{0,1\}\ & 0.597 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.509 &  \\ 
  Engineer & \{0,1\}\ & 0.796 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.864 &  \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Previous Raised & (0,40.0] & 1.096 & 3.030 & (0,10.0] & 1.101 & 1.754 \\ 
  Max Raise & [0.2,27.7] & 2.026 & 2.658 & [0.2,20.0] & 2.947 & 2.947 \\ 
  \addlinespace
  Age & [0,18] & 3.157 & 2.738 & [0,11] & 3.188 & 2.307 \\ 
  Patent & \{0,1\}\ & 0.171 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 0.161 &  \\ 
  Committed & \{0,1\}\ & 0.0188 &  & \{0,1\}\ & 1 &  \\ 
  Amount (\$K) & [0,350] & 0.273 & 5.154 & [3,350] & 15.408 & 35.627 \\ 
  \midrule
  \#Obs & 18618 & 18618 & 18618 & 330 & 330 & 330 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```